# Saving password to a .txt file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I’m teaching myself python and I’m trying to create a password generator. What I want the program to do it generate a random password and save it to a text file. What I’m having trouble with it getting the password to save to a text file. I’m able to get a password generated but I get an error code ‘in text_file file.write(output) NameError: name 'output' is not defined’ even though I already defined output. I would appreciate it if someone can tell me what I’m doing wrong. Please let me know if I need to include more information. Thanks

```
import random
import string

# Generates a password from random.choice
length = int(input('How long do you want your password? '))
x = (string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation)

def password():
    for i in range(length):
        output = print(random.choice(x),end='')

# Saves password to text file
def text_file():
    print("Would you like to save your password to a text file?")
    answer = input('y/n: ')
    if answer == 'y':
        print("One moment...")
        file = open("Password.txt","a")
        file.write(output)
        file.close()
    if answer == 'n':
        print("...")
    else:
        print("Please input y or n...")


password()
print()
print()
text_file()
```

output:

```
How long do you want your password? 18
lsR~P4Mj#K7xg3_]go

Would you like to save your password to a text file?
y/n: y
One moment...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:Password Generator.py", line 41, in <module>
    text_file()
  File "C:Password Generator.py", line 26, in text_file
    file.write(output)
NameError: name 'output' is not defined
```

Comment: This is not related to your question, but I really just have to comment. Saving passwords in a text file on your computer is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`output` isn't defined in that function.  Pass it in and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The variable Output is local variable. You need to define it as global or use argument to pass the value to text_file function.